# NumberFormatter not using the correct decimal separator for "fr_CH" locale

Tags: ios, swift

I'm just wondering if I missed something or it is some kind of bug in the `NumberFormatter`

```
let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = .currency
numberFormatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "fr_CH")
print(numberFormatter.decimalSeparator)
print(numberFormatter.string(from: 123.45))
```

The output is:

```
Optional(",")
123.45 CHF // I would expect `123,45 CHF`
```

So far, I've only found this problem for this particular region. Can anyone recreate this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
print(numberFormatter.decimalSeparator)
```

To

```
print(numberFormatter.currencyDecimalSeparator)
```

Comment: I am facepalming myself into oblivion right now. That solved the problem, thanks!!